# Atomicy operation in Couchbase 3 with java v2 driver

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to use the counter function but always it returns method not matched. So, I have the following questions :
1) How you initialize the counter name (like customerID) ?
2) When I am running mbacket.counter("customerID",1,1); I am getting counter not matched.

I am using couchbase 3 with java driver version 2.

BR/Antonis

Comment: Can you please share some examples of code you have tried so far?